# Can i modify Root.plist in settings bundle dynamically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist, root.plist

I have a settings bundle in my app.. containing **root.plist**
now i have a screen which contains a **checkbox**.. 
on pressing the check box i want to change the **BOOL** value for **DefaultValue** key of PSToggleSwitchSpecifier in the plist. 
Since its being done at runtime.. my question is that .. can the file be changed at runtime and if yes.. give an idea how to do it??

here is the plist:

```
    <plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>Username</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Username</string>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>IsSecure</key>
            <true/>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>Password</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Password</string>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSToggleSwitchSpecifier</string>    <-----toggleSwitch
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Remember</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>CheckBox</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>    <----- Default Value
            <false/>                   <---- want to change this value 
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string>Settings</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

thank you in advance **;)**

Comment: Theres a blog post for the same [here](http://iphonesdevsdk.blogspot.com/2011/04/plist.html).

Comment: this is not for root.plist i guess

Comment: Yup thats right. As Joshua has suggested you cant modify files from application bundle. I hope the above link helps you.

Comment: - you can modify files from the application bundle, if you have a jailbroken iOS device, and your app is running from within the /Applications directory

Comment: Hey @Zaraki did you find issue for your problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the settings bundle resides *inside* your app's bundle, you **cannot** change it at runtime, only at compile-time.

You can, however, use [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to set the value at runtime, and the settings application will automatically reflect this. It will be saved elsewhere, though. You can just read it back the same way as you would do with the settings bundle, also through `NSUserDefaults`.

Note that you shouldn't read from the settings bundle directly, as it makes no sense. You should always fetch and set user defaults using `NSUserDefaults`. When the user makes a change in the settings application, `NSUserDefaults` will reflect this automatically. They will always be kept in sync.

Comment: Can you please tell how to write into Settings bundle root.plist using NSUserDefaults? I am able to read the file, and I want to update the modification done in app into Root.plist in Settings bundle.

Answer (score 2):

You can not modify files with the application bundle..