# to download and install font in iphone while application running

Tags: iphone, ios, uifont

I have links to fonts from where I can download fontName.ttf. Now When user selects a particular font I want to download that and install and use it for label. 
Can I add row in Plist Fonts provided by application programatically?
And where should I save the fontName.ttf so application will use it.

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312401/dynamic-custom-fonts-loader-in-ios

Comment: This may be helpful for you to adding font in plist - Create a Plist programmatically after user action [Check it.](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/07/18/iphone-development-tutorial-create-a-plist-programmatically-after-user-action/)

Answer (score 0):

Settings bundle resides inside your app's bundle, thus - you cannot change it at runtime, only at compile-time. So it is not possible.

You could check out different solutions:

Core Text fonts: [Dynamic custom fonts loader in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312401/dynamic-custom-fonts-loader-in-ios)

NSUserDefaults: [Can i modify Root.plist in settings bundle dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941272/can-i-modify-root-plist-in-settings-bundle-dynamically)

Comment: So is there a way to use font after downloading .ttf file inside app itself?

Comment: I did as given in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312401/dynamic-custom-fonts-loader-in-ios/14555377#14555377. But Its not getting registerd. I is applied to the text. But can I register it? So I dont have to use that function always

Comment: You should create new question based on your comment to get more support on that problem.

Answer (score -1):

Not possible you can't add and delete any thing from bundle at runtime.